# listen to RTP audio stream on iOS

Tags: ios, audio-streaming, rtp, linphone

there exists the [linphone](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone) that also includes [mediastreamer2](http://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/mediastreamer2/overview) .

i would like to use it to listen to audio-only streams.
i've already set up an asterisk server to start a multicasting call.
in VLC mediaplayer, i am able to hear the streamed audio from this call.

i can not find any examples how to use mediastreamer2 to stream to my iOS app instead of VLC. 
any hints would be greatly appreciated.

cheers

UPDATE:
i found the [MobileVLCKit](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLCKit/) to fullfill my dreams :) though i am not happy with this solution as mediastreamer2 should do it too...

Comment: hey. were you able to do it with linphone?